# Segmentation of Azure Subnet for applications

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, subnet, vnet

We manage big environments inside  Azure with multiple customers, we are redesigning it and in it we wanted to manage traffic within multiple common subnets like app, web and db subnets.

So essentially no two different application inside any common subnet like db cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, resources in the different subnets from the same VNet could communicate with each other. So you need to use an [Azure network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) to filter network traffic to and from Azure resources in an Azure virtual network or subnet.

Application security groups enable you to configure network security as a natural extension of an application's structure, allowing you to group virtual machines and define network security policies based on those groups. You can reuse your security policy at scale without manual maintenance of explicit IP addresses. To learn more, see [Application security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/application-security-groups).

For PaaS like Azure app service or Azure SQL database, you could use [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#:%7E:text=The%20integration%20subnet%20can%20be,be%20in%20the%20same%20region.) to access VNet resources in a private network or use [virtual network service endpoints and rules for servers in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview).

For more information, you may know:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/dmz/secure-vnet-dmz
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/networking-overview